# Sincronização de Banco de dados Mysql entre servidores (VPS)

Tags: mysql, delphi, sincronização

Gostaria de sincronizar os meus bancos de dados que estão hospedados entre 3 VPS diferentes, gostaria de sincronizar esses dados em tempo real quando um registro for alterado numa base de dados em um determinado VPS muda-se automaticamente nas outras base de dados nas outras VPS (Programo em Delphi e aceito dicas de qualquer maneira muito obrigado) só lembrando que os servidores VPS tem Ip fixo

Comment: Você quer sincronizar apenas os dados ou quer manter uma cópia de dados e estrutura?

Comment: sincronizar apenas os dados Exemplo =  tenho as 3 VPS e em cada uma eu limito a acesso de usuários para 100 pessoas por banco em cada VPS ou seja 3 bancos para sincronizar os dados 300 pessoas vão acessar os mesmos dados em 3 VPS quero fazer isso para limitar o sobrecarregamento da VPS digamos assim quando uma VPS tiver 100 usuários o programa redireciona para o outro banco que esta sincronizado com os 3 e tempo real

Comment: Nos outros 2 haveria necessidade de leitura e escrita?

Comment: Ai que ta eu não sei pois eu quero que transformar 3 VPS com 1 banco de dados cada para se sincronizar para trabalharem com se foce um só banco

Comment: Mas estes bancos terão dados diferentes e devem sincronizar entre si? Receio que isso não é possível.

Comment: Você está precisando de um load balancing, assim poderá distribuir a carga entre os 3 servidores.

Comment: Eles vão ter as mesmas estruturas e os mesmo dados quero sincronizá-los para quando alguma coisa for altera no banco 1 da VPS 1 o banco 2 da VPS 2 e o banco 3 e VPS 3 tivesse a mesma informação alterada no banco 1 da VPS 1 e vise versa para que eles trabalhassem com um só para que nem um banco/VPS sobrecarregue com muitas pessoas acessando

Comment: Isso também me ajudaria se por algum motivo uma VPS cair eu tenho mais 2 com os mesmo dados para que minha aplicação não fique fora do AR

Comment: Postei uma resposta, você terá que analisar qual forma se adequa melhor ao seu projeto. Não há maneira muito simples de fazer isso tipo "plug-in-play", nem mesmo a mais correta.
Ao invés de ter 3 VPS vc poderia ter um dedicado com SSD ou RAID para ter uma performance melhor por exemplo. 
Tudo vai depender do teu projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O MySQL possui alguns [recurso de replicação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-solutions.html)  porém é preciso entender o escopo do seu projeto para saber qual se encaixa melhor.

O [MySQL Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) permite que os dados de um servidor de banco de dados MySQL (o mestre) sejam copiados para um ou mais servidores de banco de dados MySQL (os escravos). A replicação é assíncrona por padrão; Os escravos não precisam ser conectados permanentemente para receber atualizações do mestre. Dependendo da configuração, você pode replicar todos os bancos de dados, bancos de dados selecionados ou até mesmo tabelas selecionadas dentro de um banco de dados.

Outro recurso é [MySQL Cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-cluster.html), este permite ser configurado para Alta disponibilidade(tolerância a falhas por indisponibilidade) e Escalabilidade(capacidade e performance expansíveis). Ele possui uma configuração mais complexa porém mais robusta e com uma documentação bem rica pra se apoiar, caso tenha tempo para estudar e implementar recomendo essa técnica.

Para o seu caso em especifico, acho que uma configuração de replicação junto com um servidor de balanceamento de carga resolveria. Eu já fiz um setup usando o seguinte tutorial:

1. [Configurar uma replicação Master-to-Master (em inglês)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication)
2. [Como usar o haproxy para configurar um load balancing para mysql (em inglês)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-mysql-load-balancing--3)

Você poderia utilizar o primeiro VPS para instalar o haproxy, com uma instancia mysql rodando em localhost apenas (o haproxy irá acessalo localmente)
E com os outros 2 VPS também no balanceamento de carga.

Comment: Muito Obrigado LeonanCarvalho era isso mesmo que eu queria você me ajudo muito valeu pela atenção :)

Comment: Se a resposta resolve seu problema, vc pode marcá-la como correta e dar um voto para que ela fique no topo.
Estamos aqui apra ajudar e aprender.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer